# SyntaxError: missing } after function body in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this error: it says the missing } is after "{if(!a.document)" in the first. I've changed it a lot and didn't effect.
I've used javascript beautifier and got this code:

```
*! jQuery v1.11.3 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */ ! function(a, b) {
    "object" == typeof module && "object" == typeof module.exports ? module.exports = a.document ? b(a, !0) : function(a) {
        if (!a.document) throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
        return b(a)
    } : b(a)
}("undefined" != typeof window ? window : this, function(a, b) {
    var c = [],
        d = c.slice,
        e = c.concat,
        f = c.push,
        g = c.indexOf,
        h = {},
        i = h.toString,
        j = h.hasOwnProperty,
        k = {},
        l = "1.11.3",
        m = function(a, b) {
            return new m.fn.init(a, b)
        },
        n = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g,
        o = /^-ms-/,
        p = /-([\da-z])/gi,
        q = function(a, b) {
            return b.toUpperCase()
        };
```

It says: SyntaxError: missing } after function body
jquery.js:1:135
Cant find the error.

Comment: Do you have an un-mninified version of this JS? pretty hard to make sense of it like this

Comment: This plugin file you can download new one, otherwise use javascript  beautifier editor.

Comment: Dear @Samyappa I beautified it as you told

Comment: Not an answer but a useful hint: Get into the habit to intend braces on their own line. This way, code becomes much more readable and finding brace errors is just a matter of scrolling to positions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just snipped out a portion of [jQuery 1.11.3](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js).  Why?  It's not even a sensical snippet, since it contains a `:` that originally followed a `?` as part of the trinary operator.